# How to get a true or false value based on a random list

Tags: python, user-input

I currently have a "for fun" program idea that I'm undertaking. Essentially, the program spits out a quote and the user has to say if it's real or made up (1 and 2 as the input). My current code is
`

```
#the point of the code is to select a random quote from either t or f and use user input to see if they think it's real or fake
import random
def conserv():
    t="This is a test true quote","This is another true quote" #quote variables
    f="This is a test fake quote","This is also fake"
    fact=0
    while fact=0: #setting up a while loop
        u=int(input("is the following quote real or did I make it up? ")) #Variables will be defined in the welcome function
        l=random.randchoice(t,f) #select a either t or f at random
        if l==t and u==1: #if the true list is selected and they say it's true
            print("yes! that is a real quote!")
        if l==t and u==2: #if the true list is selected and they say it's false
            print("nope, that is real")
        if l==f and u==1: #if the false list is selected and they say it's true
            print("nope, I actually made it up")
        if l==f and u==2: #if the false is selected and they say it's false
            print("correct! I made it up")
        if u==0:
            return #end the program
def welcome():
    print("Welcome to fact or BS! I give you a quite and you type in 1 if it's true, 2 if it's false, or 0 to end the program!")
def main():
    welcome()
    conserv()
```

`

```
what am I doing wrong here?


I tried messing with indentation but I'm not sure what exactly to try from there
```

Comment: `while fact=0:` does not look right to me - probably needs to be `while fact==0:`

Comment: separately, don't comment the programming language.  Comment (rarely) the implementation.  When you have this working you *might* want to take it over to code review, because quite a lot here could be improved.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a specific question here.  What doesn't happen and what should?  Don't mess with indentation: use it to say what you want to say.

Comment: you didn't call the main function. what are u expecting with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code:-

line no.7 it's `while fact==0`

you are checking a condition here. so you need to put two equals.

line no.9 module 'random' has no attribute `randchoice` it is `choice` only.
You need to put the argument as list or some other iteratives.

Atlast you didn't even call the `main()` function.

```
#the point of the code is to select a random quote from either t or f and use user input to see if they think it's real or fake
import random
def conserv():
    t="This is a test true quote","This is another true quote" #quote variables
    f="This is a test fake quote","This is also fake"
    list = [t,f]
    fact=0
    while fact==0: #setting up a while loop
        u=int(input("is the following quote real or did I make it up? ")) #Variables will be defined in the welcome function
        l=random.choice(list) #select a either t or f at random
        if l==t and u==1: #if the true list is selected and they say it's true
            print("yes! that is a real quote!")
        if l==t and u==2: #if the true list is selected and they say it's false
            print("nope, that is real")
        if l==f and u==1: #if the false list is selected and they say it's true
            print("nope, I actually made it up")
        if l==f and u==2: #if the false is selected and they say it's false
            print("correct! I made it up")
        if u==0:
            return #end the program
def welcome():
    print("Welcome to fact or BS! I give you a quite and you type in 1 if it's true, 2 if it's false, or 0 to end the program!")
def main():
    welcome()
    conserv()

main()
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as variable name, it is a standard type and function in python.